# Is there a simple function to change the values rows of an array to columns in another array?

Tags: python, numpy

Okay, I have an array that has 5 rows and one column.  I have another array with 5 columns, and 1 row.  Is there a way that I can change the values of the array with the rows to the columns in a simpler way.  I know that I can do this:

```
 import numpy as np
 x = np.ones(5)
 y = np.zeros([5,1])
 y[:,0] = x
```

Is there a easier way of doing this.  I will be flipping many values in rows to columns, and this may get messy in my actual code.

Comment: You can transpose it? `y = x.T` (if x has shape (1, 5))

Comment: "I have another array with 5 columns, and 1 row" - in your posted code, you don't. You have a 1-dimensional array with 5 elements and no concept of rows or columns. This distinction is important.

Comment: Since `x` is 1d, shape (5,), `x[:,None]` is a nice of giving it a (5,1) shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

```
y = x.reshape((5,1))
```

Comment: Cleaner: `x.reshape(y.shape)`

Comment: I supposed that `y` may not be defined yet.

Comment: Okay, make sense